# how to let user drop interactive pin/marker on one uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uikit

Right now I am working on one application which needs to have an interactive image.

While the user is viewing this image, they should be able to drop pin/marker onto the image by tap any location on the image. Once a pin/marker is dropped on the image, user should be able to tap the pin/marker again to add some comments to the pin, delete this pin/marker or even some other operation.

Right now, I am using the MKOverlayView to hold my image and put the MKOverlayView into a MKMapView so that I can use customized annotations to do that. However, there are always some zooming issues when I limited the visible region of the view(Because I do not need the entire world map). More importantly, I find out that I cannot get rid of the leftbuttom legal link(I need to submit my app to app store. And Apple does not allow it.) Also, each time when I first load the app, I can definitely see the mapping is loading and the map grid. And I do not want user to see it.

So I am thinking to find some other ways. Can anyone provide me a more feasible way to implement it, like some similar project example or tutorial? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same question.

Comment: @user3285918 I convert the entire image into pdf. Therefore, instead of dropping pin, I drop annotation to the pdf file. This is my solution.